# Powershell script to list LastContentModifiedDate

Tags: 2007, powershell

I'm a beginner to Powershell 1.0 and I'm looking to pull some information out of the Sharepoint 2007 farm as we start the upgrade to 2010 planning.  This is what I'm wanting to do, but having some difficulty visualizing how to string it all together.

I want to iterate through all the webs in all site collections in a web application and list the site URL and the LastContentModifiedDate in the output and ideally output it to a csv or text file for analysis in Excel.

I can get the web app I want by using `$spweb = get-spwebapplication | where{ $_.Displayname -like "*collab*"}` but I'm not sure how to get all the site collections from the web app to iterate through all the spwebs.

I'm importing the functions into my profile provided by [Zach Rosenfield](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/zach/Script%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer

I'm pretty sure that Get-SPWebApplication does not work with WSS 3.0 or MOSS 2007 (unless you have a custom cmdlet), but the code you need is below.

```
foreach ($wa in get-spwebapplication | where{ $_.Displayname -like "*collab*"})
{
    Write-Host $wa
    foreach ($site in $wa.Sites)
    {
        Write-Host $site
        foreach ($web in $site.Webs)
        {
            Write-Host $web         
        }
    } 
}
```

You just need to get the data required on each $web and do something with it.

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm not sure how to get a list of site collections to pass into that.  To get site information (to get webs), I need to do a Get-SPSite call which requires a url parameter.  So I don't know how to go from a web app to a list of site collections in that web application.

Comment: Updated the code sample - should help you out better.

Comment: It wasn't pretty but I used what you had and came up with this: `foreach ($wa in get-spwebapplication | where{ $_.Displayname -like "*collab*"})
{    
 #Write-Host $wa    
 foreach ($site in $wa.Sites)    
 {        
  #Write-Host $site.url, $Site.LastContentModifiedDate        
  foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)        
  {            
   write-output "URL" $web.url | out-File C:\out.txt -append
   write-output "Last MOdified" $Site.LastContentModifiedDate | out-File C:\out.txt -append
        
  }    
 } 
}`